# Resharper Navigate to MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper, visual-studio-2013

I recently upgraded to **Resharper** 8.1 and **VS 2013**

Before I could **ctrl+click** on a **View** to jump to it, but this no longer works. Is there a feature I need to enable to get it back?

```
 PartialView("_MainMenu", viewModel);
```

Comment: Do you have VS 2013 or VS 2013 Update 1? And the second question: which version of ASP.NET MVC do you have currently installed?

Comment: VS 2013 Update 1 with MVC 5.1

Comment: Check if the `Go to Declaration on <Control + Left Click> in editor` option is enabled on `Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> Search & Navigation`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Go to Resharper->Manage Extensions and click the Online tab. Then search for Resharper.ExternalAnnotations, and install the package it comes up with.

[image]

Finally go to Visual Studio Tools->Options and go to the Resharper->General options page. Click Suspend Now followed by Resume to restart Resharper.

[image]

Comment: This **should** be the the accepted answer.  Well done @Samuel-Jack

Comment: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/40213828-Missing-ReSharper-features-after-applying-MVC-5-1-nuget-update-

Comment: @MotoWilliams not to be picky but I think you intended the emphasis  on the **This** as in **This** should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Just running the update is an option for those that have an earlier version.

Comment: Is this still the solution? I'm running VS 2015 and the Resharper 2016.2 and there is no such ExternalAnnotations package under manage extensions. Does anyone have any suggestions? I've been trying to fix this issue for a while now. Ctrl+m + Ctrl+g works, but how do I map that to alt+click?

Answer (score 20):

About workaround for previous versions of ReSharper:

You can download package with annotations https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/package/ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations/8.1.1000.431 and unpack content of `ReSharper\vAny\annotations\` folder to `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\vX.Y\Bin\ExternalAnnotations`, where X.Y is your version of ReSharper.

Better first to clean target folder up to avoid annotations duplicates.

Comment: This one solved the problem while leaving me on the production Resharper version.

Comment: You can use Resharper's Extension Manager to install this too.

Comment: New version 8.2.3001 (for MVC 5.2) https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/package/ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations/8.2.3001

Comment: This solved. None of other solutions were working. That directory wasn't created by installing plugins with VS.

Answer (score 6):

ReSharper 8.2.1 (8.2.1000.4556) doesn't support MVC 5.2

[EAP for 8.2 is closed](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Early+Access+Program)

[Bug registered](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-417526)

**UPDATE:**

FIXED: [reply about fix from the Resharper team](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-417526#comment=27-766734)

> You need to restart the VS and you will get notification about Update or run it manually from the Resharper => Extension Manager => Updates => Resharper.ExternalAnnotations (like in the Samuel answer)

Comment: Seems that you are right. I've someone wants to test this just try switching the assemblies of `System.Web.Mvc.dll version=5.2` to `System.Web.Mvc.dll version=5.1` or earlier and intellisense for Ctrl+Click will begin to work

Answer (score 4):

There still seems to be an issue with ReSharper and navigating to MVC Views or having the QuickFix (Alt+Enter) functionality available on them in the latest (as of this writing) version of ReSharper - v8.2.3000.5176.

My MVC version is 5.2.  My ReSharper version is 8.2.3000.5176. When I installed this it seemed to install the ExternalAnnotations that come bundled with the update, also versioned at the same version number.

I can fix the issue by uninstalling the ExternalAnnotations (version 8.2.3000.5176) and re-installing the latest version offered from the ReSharper Gallery (which is version 8.2.2001.1). After a Visual Studio restart, my MVC quick-fixes and View navigation is back.

Strangely, I also get prompted by ReSharper that extension updates are available, and it wants to upgrade my ExternalAnnotations to version 8.2.3000.5176. If I do this (and restart VS) everything breaks again. Downgrading back to version 8.2.2001.1 (and a VS restart) will, however, fix it again.

A number of other people are [also reporting this issue on JetBrain's ReSharper blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/10/10/resharper-8-2-3-is-available/) that announced ReSharper 8.2.3

So, if you're using MVC 5.2.x and ReSharper 8.2.3, try to *downgrade* the version of the ExternalAnnotations that you're using and see if that solves the issue.

**UPDATE (5th November 2014):**
There is now a new version of the ReSharper External Annotations available from the JetBrains "ReSharper Gallery".  This new version is v8.2.3001 and I can confirm that once installed, this new version fixes the problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper 8.1 just doesn't support MVC 5.1

[Latest EAP builds](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+8.1.1+EAP) of ReSharper 8.1.1 do.

Comment: Any idea if previous versions of Resharper will have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problems with running your **ctrl+click** and no additional configuration (enabling/disabling anything) should be needed. So it is most probably some bug.

Your situation might be connected with the following known issue reported [here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-and-web-tools-20132-preview-for-visual-studio-2013-release-notes#mvc).  It is connected with IntelliSense, not with Resharper directly, but they are both related to problems with navigating in Razor engine when having VS 2013 and newest ASP.NET MVC.

Below the summary of the issue description and some workaround to fix it:

> MVC 5.1 Tooling Support and Razor IntelliSense are Still Broken Even
>   After Installing VS2013 Update 1 RC
>
> Known issue:
>
> If a VS2013 user installed “Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for
>   Visual Studio 2013” before they install VS2013 Update 1 RC, they won’t
>   be able to get MVC 5.1 tooling support that comes with VS2013 Update 1
>   RC.
>
> Symptom:
>
> MVC 5.1 tooling support and Razor IntelliSense are still broken even
>   after installing VS2013 Update 1 RC.
>
> Workaround:
>
> From "Add/Remove Program", uninstall "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools
>   2013.1 for Visual Studio 2013" Repair VS2013 RTM Install VS2013 update 1 RC if you have not yet installed it. If you have already installed
>   this, you don’t need to reinstall or repair it. From Web PI, reinstall
>   Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2013 or
>   repair Azure SDK 2.2.

Comment: It's like a SHIFT+DELETE suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

try `ctrl+B` while cursor some where on the View()

Comment: What does it do? Looks like there is no default shortcut for CTRL+B