# Resharper vs2013 CTRL+Click not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, resharper-8.0

I have installed reshaper 8.1.23 and visual studio 2013 update 1.

I'd like to navigate to assembly when I hold Ctrl + click. for example holding Ctrl on IdentityUser class and Click should bring IdentityUser class but nothing happen. I also have done what has mentioned here [Resharper Navigate to MVC View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488176/resharper-navigate-to-mvc-view) but with no success. when i press f12 it goes to the desired class but in previous version of resharper it was done by resharper.

Comment: Do you get an underline when you hold Ctrl at all? Have you installed Productivity Power Tools lately?

Comment: Yes, recently I have installed productivity power tools, it shows the underlined  selection and it works on views and methods that are not in assembly and are not compiled. I want to be able to open assembly as in in case for example what f12 key does on IdentityUser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without additional information, I think what happened is that Productivity Power Tools taken over your Ctrl-Click action. You could turn it off from **Tools - Options - Productivity Power Tools**, and disable **Ctrl + Click to Peek Definition**. This should make Ctrl-Click be used by ReSharper again, and it will navigate to decompiled code when source is not available.

Comment: Under Tools - Options - Productivity Power Tools - Other Extensions -> Untick -> "Control click shows definition in Peek"

Comment: In VS2017, This option is now under **Tools > Options > Text Editor > General** and Untick "Enable mouse click to perform Go To Definition"

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was going into ReSharper -> Options -> Keyboard & Menus and re-applying my keyboard-scheme:

[image: Apply scheme in Resharper]

Answer (score 0):

There might be a bug with this version of resharper.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488176/resharper-navigate-to-mvc-view) explains which version you should download in order for it to work. It's consistent with what I've encounterd when I was using resharper 8.1