# Resharper ctrl click not working Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

Resharper has suddenly decided that <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> click and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> click are no longer a thing.

I've applied the resharper scheme again

Cleared the resharper cache

Reset the visual studio keyboard Tools > Environment -> Keyboard

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I cleared my resharper cache, restarted visual studio and my machine. I then re-ticked rich mouse navigation in the editor and this resolved the issue for me.

---

Older answer:

So after tearing my non-existent hair out, re-starting the machine and upgrading resharper, I managed to solve this.

Resharper - Options - Environment - Search & Navigation - Rich mouse navigation in the editor.

Untick Go to Declaration on *Control + Left Click*

Untick Go to Implementation on *Control + Alt + Left Click*

For some reason unticking these actually enables the feature? I'm presuming that I have some feature overriding these somewhere.

Anyway it solved my issue, hopefully this helps someone else in the future with the same issue.

Comment: BTW, I've consistently had this issue. At some point during a coding session or after opening VS enough times, it reverts back to the standard Ctrl + Click to View definition. I have yet to be able to resolve this once and for all.

Comment: Clear Caches worked for me. For anyone who is/was not aware where is that (like me): Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> General, on the bottom there is a button Clear Caches. Click it and restart VS.

Comment: Turning it off, then restarting VS, and then turning it on again worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

There's one more possible culprit (at least in Visual Studio 2017). If none of the solutions work (like for me). You should go to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General
```

and turn off the `Enable mouse click to perform Go To Definition` or change the modifier key to something else.

Comment: The solution which really works in VS 2017 Resharper.

Comment: YES! You are my personal hero for today. That fixed it for me!

Comment: VS2017 added their own ctrl-click navigation so you need to untick it. https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000670304-Ctrl-Left-Click-Wrong-Location

Comment: This also solved my problem of not beeing able to go forward/backward via mouse buttons. Thx :)

Answer (score 29):

Thank you @SmartK8 for your answer.  I have Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.4) and ReSharper 2017.2.1.  I have found that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**-Click** will actually navigate ***twice*** in this scenario.  It is super annoying and depending on where your mouse is and where you land you can actually navigate twice.
You can tell this is happening because of the "double underline" on the navigation UI hint.  Check it out:

[image]

To turn off Visual Studio's navigate option, go to: **Tools > Options > Text Editor > General**.  And vote up @SmartK8's answer for this wisdom!  Now only ReSharper's navigation will remain.

Alternately, you can turn off ReSharper's navigation by going to **ReSharper > Options > Search & Navigation**.  Uncheck **Rich mouse navigation in the editor**.

I have decided to keep ReSharper's navigation since I can go to definition or implementation.  (Going to implementation is nice when a method is declared in an interface).

Haha, and for the double underline?  The underline that is 1 pixel below is the Visual Studio one.  The underline that is 3 pixels below is the ReSharper one!

Answer (score 2):

Got Productivity Power Tools installed? It also has a go to definition that clashes with Resharper's.

Turn off Productivity Power Tools' "Control-Click Go To Definition" in Options => Productivity Power Tools => Turn Extensions On/Off.

I'd imagine the same goes for any other extension that does the same thing. Try finding them by typing "Control click" in the Quick Launch TextBox at the top-right of Visual Studio.

Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148763/492

Comment: I can confirm that "Productivity Power Tools" and Resharper are fighting over this feature. 
Switching it off in either extension makes it work by letting the other extension handle it.

Answer (score 1):

None of the provided solutions worked for me. What caused ctrl+click to stop working is when my resharper license ran out.

A few ways to disable resharper to get it working again:

- Tools -> Options -> Resharper -> General -> Suspend Now
- Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Installed -> JetBrains Resharper xx -> Disable. Restart Visual Studio.
- Extensions -> Resharper -> Options -> Keyboard -> Shortcut Scheme -> Keyboar Scheme -> None

Answer (score 0):

This action will enable Ctrl + Click function in Resharper

- In the **Tools | External Sources** in **Resharper Options**
- Select **Navigation to Sources**
- Save