# VisualStudio/Resharper tools are missing since MVC upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I upgraded to MVC5 and ever since I did so I've noticed that a bunch of functionality seems to be missing.

Example:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Used to be that if I hit Ctrl+B on "View" it would take me to the .cshtml view file (MyAction.cshtml).  Same thing in the actual view files.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyFormAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post)) {...etc.}
```

When Ctrl+B was used on the "MyFormAction" text, it would go to that controller action.

I've migrated to VS2013, upgraded to Resharper8 (was going to do these things anyway) thinking it all would just come back, but no.

Any ideas??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resharper Navigate to MVC View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488176/resharper-navigate-to-mvc-view)

Comment: Please also see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503408/57477) for this same issue which seems to affect MVC 5.2.X & ReSharper 8.2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you upgraded to MVC 5.1

Look at this question [Resharper Navigate to MVC View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488176/resharper-navigate-to-mvc-view)

In short, go to to Extension Manager and install latest annotations package.