# Resharper view resolve stopped working after general NuGet update

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, nuget

After updating all packages in NuGet manager, I've noticed that the view resolvement feature of Resharper have stopped working. I can't navigate to the view, and I no longer have the option of creating a new view.

A lot of packages were updated, among them MVC and Razor.

Comment: Please also see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26503408/57477) for this same issue which seems to affect MVC 5.2.X & ReSharper 8.2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ReSharper 8, you need to update to the latest ReSharper 8.2, and make sure you update ReSharper's extension 'External Annotations'. This will pull the updated files that are required for MVC and Razor support.

If you're using a previous version of ReSharper, here's a [workaround by @derigel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21588672/8205) you could use:

> About workaround for previous versions of ReSharper:
>
> You can download package with annotations
>   https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/api/v2/package/ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations/8.1.1000.431
>   and unpack content of `ReSharper\vAny\annotations\` folder to
>   `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\JetBrains\ReSharper\vX.Y\Bin\ExternalAnnotations`, where X.Y is
>   your version of ReSharper.
>
> Better first to clean target folder up to avoid annotations
>   duplicates.

Comment: It worked. Required an additional restart of the computer, though. Thanks!

Comment: @HaroldSmith Awesome! Glad to hear it worked, though it's strange you had to restart your computer, I'd think simply restarting VS would do the trick :) Also, thanks! PT (and Steven Wilson in general) are amazing!

Comment: Restarting VS was enough for me.