# ReSharper 8.2.1 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.0

I've recently tried to install ReSharper 8.2.1 on my new computer for Visual Studio 2013. The install process succeeds but when I open Visual studio, there is no ReSharper Tab at the top.

In Tools -> Options, ReSharper is there and i can click the Suspend Now button, but the Options.. button has no effect.

Is there something i'm missing? or a setting I have forgotten?

Comment: Did you try solutions from the following articles: http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21204867 or http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/26859128?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. I tried reinstalling it with admin privileges, repairing it, suspending and restarting it etc. but nothing seemed to work. I eventually deleted the %AppData%\JetBrains\ReSharper as stated by some people in the comments on this post, which finally fixed everything.

http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21204867

Comment: Thanks! It's help!

Comment: Still works up to date, although the name of the folder now is `ReSharperPlatformVs12` or `ReSharperPlatformVs14` (etc) depending on the VS version (where 12 is 2013 and 14 is 2015).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it updtating ReSharper.ExternalAnnotations to the last version like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488176/resharper-navigate-to-mvc-view) mentions.

If you don't have it yet you can download it by going to

Resharper => Extension Manager => Updates => Resharper.ExternalAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost an entire day getting Resharper 9.2 working with VS 2013 Premium. 
Followed the steps mentioned at http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206104038-ReSharper-is-not-available-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation without any success.

Finally what worked for me was to repair the VS 2013 setup.

(This is not relevant to the question posted as the question is for Resharper 8.1. However, I am posting this as someone might find it useful and may not end up wasting time like me!)