# unable to apply Bootstrap classes to my EditorFor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, editorfor

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application , and i wrote the following :-

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
&
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control"  })
```

but this will not have any effect on the generated html, but if i changed the `EditorFor` to be T`extboxFor` i will get the effect for the form-control class ? can anyone advice on this please ? i read that this is supported only inside asp.net mvc 5.1 ? so what are the available approaches i can follow to get this working other than upgrading my asp.net mvc-5 to asp.net mvc 5.1 , to eliminate the risk of upgrading?
Can anyone adivce ?

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576209/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-adding-class-to-editorfor

Comment: so how i can modify assign the class inside the editor template ??

Comment: Can you show your editor template code?  The accepted answer on that post I referenced (with 106 upvotes!) indicates that specifying 'the class' for an Editor template _does not make sense_ because the template may contain many pieces of markup (in contrast to a TextboxFor which renders only one tag).  The answer also shows _how to apply a class to a tag within the Editor Template_.  Which part is not clear?

Comment: @johnG, If you want to specify the class in the `EditorFor()` method, you can pass it as `AdditionalViewData` as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341031/adding-class-to-editorfor-in-mvc/27341257#27341257)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the reply, but seems that if i want to use "htmlAttributes " inside the editorfor i will need to upfrage my project from mvc5.0 to mvc5.1 or to mvc5.2 ...

Comment: @DavidTansey but from the replies yo can see that changing the EditorFor to be TextBoxfor will raise an issue that TextBoxFor doesn't honor the DisplayFormat set. !! so that why i do not want to modify the EditorFor template, to be TextBoxFor!

Comment: @johnG, No you don't (although you can) - the answer in the link shows how do do it with MVC-4

Comment: @johnG, and further to you comment to David, you can also use `@ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue` to get the value defined by the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke now  i am confused , inside the link you mentioned to use "new { htmlAttributes }" inside Editorfor but this can not be done inside asp.net mvc5 and i need to update to mvc1.0 ... because inside mvc5.0 it will raise an error that can not add new { htmlAttributes}  to editorfor .. not sure what do you mean the link show how to do it in mvc4? can u advice ?

Comment: @johnG, I was referring to the link I provided in my first comment - **[this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341031/adding-class-to-editorfor-in-mvc/27341257#27341257)**. In any case I have added an answer that you can use in MVC-5.0 with some options you can consider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, to pass html attributes to a standard `EditorFor()` you need MVC-5.1+. If you want to replicate this with MVC-5, you can create a custom editor template and pass the attributes using the overload that accepts `additionViewData`. For example, create a new `EditorTemplate` named "String.cshtml" to apply the template for all properties that are typeof `string`

`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, ViewData["attributes"])
```

and in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { attributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

or create a specific`EditorTemplate`

`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyCustomTemplate.cshtml`

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
```

and in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, "MyCustomTemplate", new { attributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

The second example shows how to respect the `DisplayFormat` attribute as mentioned in your comments above, for example

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

will format the value as a currency string.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162218/editortemplate-for-dropdownlist/26417466#26417466) also gives some other options including creating a custom html helper for rendering bootstrap controls

Comment: thanks for the reply, seems the easiest way is to upgrade my mvc5.0 to mvc 5.2.2 . but is upgrading from asp.net mvc5 to mvc5.2.2 , include running the following command Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.2 ? or there are other manual steps?

Comment: As far as I know the Nuget package should update the web.config files correctly (worked for me for 5.0 > 5.1 but I haven't done 5.2 yet). Check the prerequisites [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/announcing-the-release-of-asp-net-mvc-5-2-web-api-2-2-and-web-pages-3-2.aspx) so you dont have the problems described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343714/mvc-5-mvc-5-1-migration-intellisense-issues). As always, make sure you have a backup :)

Comment: thanks for the reply. now i am not using webAPi so i do not need to update it , is this correct ? or it is better to update both asp.net mvc to 5.2.2 and webapi to 5.2.2 and also the Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages  to Version 3.2.0?

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Created, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "date" } })
```