# Override CSS for @Html.EditorFor is not working MVC5

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Asp.Net MVC4 technology. I'm trying to override default style property of Html.EditorFor but its not working.
Here is my code.
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`
And here is output from the browser.

```
<input id="Name" class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true"data-val-required="The User Name field is required." name="Name" type="text"/>
```

Comment: This code looks fine. I just copied and pasted that line to a local project and it did add that css class to the input form element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to apply Bootstrap classes to my EditorFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975810/unable-to-apply-bootstrap-classes-to-my-editorfor)

Comment: Adding html attributes with `EditorFor()` is only supported in MVC-5.1+. Use `TextBoxFor()`

Comment: Thanks..... I just Updated my MVC version and it worked.